# Is it possible to dynamically replace the fields in a graphql/apollo query as well as variables?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

I use the following query and get values.

```
 const GET_VALUES = gql`
   query getValues (
     $date_begin: String!
     $date_end: String!
   ) {
       production (order_by: {datetime: desc}, 
                     where: {value94: {_gt: "0"}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_gt: $date_begin}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_lt: $date_end}}}}
       ){
           datetime
           value10
           value11
        }
    }
 `;
```

Can i use "datetime, value10, value11" dynamically like:

```
 const GET_VALUES = gql`
   query getValues (
     $date_begin: String!
     $date_end: String!
     $q_values: String!
   ) {
       production (order_by: {datetime: desc}, 
                     where: {value94: {_gt: "0"}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_gt: $date_begin}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_lt: $date_end}}}}
       ){
          $q_values
        }
    }
 `;
```

I got:

Error: [nuxt] Error while mounting app: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $

```
GraphQL request (13:12)
12: 
13:            $q_values
               ^
14:         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible.  With the graphql decorator, the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) still replaces placeholders (eg `${expression}`).  For example

```
 let q_values = "datetime, value10, value11"
 const GET_VALUES = gql`
   query getValues (
     $date_begin: String!
     $date_end: String!
   ) {
       production (order_by: {datetime: desc}, 
                     where: {value94: {_gt: "0"}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_gt: $date_begin}, 
                     _and: {datetime: {_lt: $date_end}}}}
       ){
           ${q_values}
        }
    }
 `;
```

Edit: Also, since you're using vue-apollo check out [reactive query definition](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#reactive-query-definition).